# How to stop unwanted tilde character appearing in git bash windows?

Tags: windows, git, windows-10, git-bash, tilde

**How to stop unwanted tilde character appearing in git bash windows?**

I am using Git bash in windows 10. Facing an weird problem. Tilde character is automatically appearing in the bash window sometimes which is causing my normal workflow tedious. Why it is appearing and how can I stop it?

[image]

For example, After running a `pull rebase`, I spent some time to have a coffee and after coming back I found three tildes in the console which I never wrote myself.

Comment: Screenshot may help here. Do you mean before the prompt? `~` indicates your home directory

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I have added the screenshot describing the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time I have seen this is with a program preventing your computer going to sleep, like [caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/).

That kind of program would send every 30 seconds a character (see [isse 00087](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/support/kb.pl?q=00087)), which, if your bash CMD is in focus, would appear on said CMD shell session.

In your case, it could be another program (since caffeine generates faked <kbd>F15</kbd> keypress which normally would trigger `8~`, nbot just `~` alone), but the general idea remains.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan No problem. I had the exact same issue on my workstation!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with caffeine. If you want to use caffeine and terminal, here is how I fixed this:

1. Create a shortcut to caffeine.exe
2. Right click the shortcut, click "Properties". Go to "Shortcut" tab.
3. Under "Target" you should see the path to the .exe file. After that path add the "-useshift" option. (eg. if the path under target was `C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\caffeine.exe` change it to `C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\caffeine.exe -useshift`
4. Whenever you run caffeine, use this shOrtcut instead.